# ASP.NET MVC validation with error: E_DEFAULT_LOCALE_NOT_DEFINED

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, globalization

When validating a currency format `decimal` in an ASP.NET MVC application, I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: E_DEFAULT_LOCALE_NOT_DEFINED: Default locale has not been defined.
>
> at createError (globalize.js:105)
>   at validate (globalize.js:182)
>   at validateDefaultLocale (globalize.js:213)
>   at Function.Globalize.numberParser.Globalize.numberParser (number.js:1422)
>   at Function.Globalize.parseNumber.Globalize.parseNumber (number.js:1474)
>   at $.validator.methods.number (jquery.validate.globalize.js:21)
>   at $.validator.check (jquery.validate.js:777)
>   at $.validator.element (jquery.validate.js:492)
>   at $.validator.onfocusout (jquery.validate.js:300)
>   at HTMLInputElement.delegate (jquery.validate.js:423)

This is when trying to validate the currency format for a `price` form field. For you information here are the most important aspects of my app.

This is the `Startup.cs` file

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var defaultCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
    var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture),
        SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { defaultCulture },
        SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { defaultCulture }
    };
    app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
}
```

This is the `bower.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-validation": "1.17.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "v3.3.7",
    "cldrjs": "0.4.8",
    "jquery-validation-globalize": "1.0.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "cldrjs": "0.4.8"
  }
}
```

This is the `.bowerrc` file:

```
{
    "directory": "wwwroot/lib",
    "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "npm install cldr-data-downloader@0.2.x",
        "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/cldr-data-downloader/bin/download.js -i bower_components/cldr-data/index.json -o bower_components/cldr-data/"
    }
}
```

And finally here is the snipet of the `_template` file that populates the view so the `globalization` takes place in the whole page:

```
<!-- cldr scripts (needed for globalize) -->
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>

<!-- globalize scripts -->
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/date.js"></script>

<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-globalize/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>
```

The thing is that whenever i try to get the validation it goes on without making it and posting the error mentioned. I have reviewed the previous posts related to this kind of error but all of them are related to plain `javascript` files and configuration.

I have installed `Microsoft.NETCore 2.0` in **Visual Studio 2017** with a **Windows 10 machine** all up to date. The idea of this is to review why the error happens and how to properly set the globalization `Default Locale` properly if some one knows how to do it.